# variable sed pattern to remove string

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have a very large file I need to remove a pattern from. The problem is, there are no newline separators in the file. The pattern to remove looks like this: `... 1666 more items` where 1666 can be any number.

Comment: What happens with a simple `sed 's/... [0-9]* more items//g'`? Is there an error because the "line" is too long?

Comment: _"very large file"_  How large?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `sed` is the best tool for this. I personally go to `perl` for such things, and have come up with this:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $/ = " more items"; } s/\.\.\.\s\d+ more items$//;'
```

`-e` is the program text to execute.

`-p` means to do an implicit loop over the program text once per record (by default a record is a line, see below for modifying that).

This first sets the record separator `$/` from the default newline (`\n`) to the string " more items"; the block indicated by `BEGIN { }` is done once at the beginning.

Now it will read the input one chunk at a time, up to (and including) the record separator. So every loop you have "whatever ... 1234 more items" in the input buffer.

The `s/\.\.\.\s\d+ more items$//` is a substitution which removes any string of three dots (escaped to remove the special meaning of "any character"), followed by a space (\s), followed by one or more digits (`\d+`) and the text " more items" at the end of the record (`$`). Matching the end of the record should not be necessary but might speed up the matching.

The result is printed by default due to the `-p` option.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNU sed (sometimes called `gsed`), then long lines are fine up to the limit of memory.

If you are using other sed, such as on MacOS or BSD, there will be limits.  The [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Limitations) explains:

> For those who want to write portable sed scripts, be aware that some
>   implementations have been known to limit line lengths (for the pattern
>   and hold spaces) to be no more than 4000 bytes. The POSIX standard
>   specifies that conforming sed implementations shall support at least
>   8192 byte line lengths. GNU sed has no built-in limit on line length;
>   as long as it can malloc() more (virtual) memory, you can feed or
>   construct lines as long as you like.

Thus, if you have GNU sed, you can use a sed solution such as suggested by [@philippos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/216004/philippos):

```
sed 's/\.\.\. [0-9]* more items//g'
```

#### Using awk

As an alternative, if you have GNU awk (sometimes called `gawk`), try:

```
awk -v RS='\.\.\. [0-9]* more items' 1 ORS="" File
```

Thus uses the regex `\.\.\. [0-9]* more items` as the *record separator* on input and the empty string as the *record separator* on output.  This has the effect of removing any match of the regex `\.\.\. [0-9]* more items`.

Because awk only reads in one record at a time, this will consume less memory than the sed solution.